# using cursor db2

Tags: sql, db2, cursor

how to run cursor in sql editor (without function or procedure) i'm currently using db2 9.7

Comment: Your question is not clear, please add details such as an SQL statement.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

In Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, you cannot declare a cursor outside of a block . A named block can be in a routine (like a function or a stored procedure, or an embedded-SQL main program etc ), or in an anonymous (unnamed) block (using `begin ... end`, or `begin atomic ... end` ).

Look at the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000937.html), which states "

> Although an interactive SQL facility might provide an interface that
> gives the appearance of interactive execution, this statement can only
> be embedded within an application program. It is not an executable
> statement and cannot be dynamically prepared

. "

By *application program* the documentation means a block (like in a routine or anonymous block or embedded-SQL main program).